# Rest POST request with jersey

Tags: java, json, rest, curl

I am try to call REST web service from curl, in linux, Also use jersey
then it returns

```
A message body reader for Java type, class mypackage.UserGroupsData, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
```

Mappign class is

```
public class UserGroupsData {
private int id;
private String name;    
public int getId() {
    return id;
} public void setId(int id) {
   this.id = id;
}public String getName() {
    return name;
}public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
} public int getId() {
    return id;
}}
```

My POST method id

```
@POST
@Path("/getQualifiedNumbers")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response getQualifiedNumbers(UserGroupsData userGroup){            
    return Response.status(201).entity(userGroup).build();        
}
```

Curl command which i used to call is

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id":"1","name":"e"}' http://localhost:8080/url/getQualifiedNumbers
```

Server is jetty

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add annotation "@XmlRootElement" in your class. it should become like:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class UserGroupsData {
private int id;
private String name;    
public int getId() {
    return id;
} public void setId(int id) {
   this.id = id;
}public String getName() {
    return name;
}public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
} public int getId() {
    return id;
}}
```

Comment: No Its not working,  I used jersey 1.0, now updated to 1.8 now i having java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/spi/service/ComponentProvider issue , i have com.sun.jersey 1.0 in my pom , can it be a issue ?

Comment: The dependencies in Jersey need to be compatible to the version that you use. you should download all the jars from the version 1.8. so what you mentioned could be the reason. my answer solves the original issue that you posted.

Comment: No AJ , putting @XmlRootElement not fixed the original issue, but some how i realized that lower version was the issue. thats why i updated the version to 1.8 , now the problem is  com.sun.jersey latest version is 1.0, i think that is the reason for the issue i mentioned in the above comment

Comment: without using "@XmlRootElement" i don't think jersey will serialize the class object to JSON, regardless of what version you use.

Comment: check http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html and get jersey from there. If you want to not manage all dependencies by yourself, try the "jersey-bundle.jar" and "asm.jar" from the section "11.1. Core server".

Comment: > It is working without "@XmlRootElement" only with jersey 1.4 or latest, i tried it by creating sample application, btw thanks for your valuable comments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20672/discussion-between-user1573690-and-a-j)